# How to put my OneNote notes from my machine to onedrive?

Tags: macos, synchronization, onenote, recover

I have several notes on my OneNote on mac. I accidentally deleted the OneNote file on my OneDrive.
I have a copy of the notes on my mac but It is, understandably not able to synch with the server because the file is not there on the server.
**How do I put the notes I have on my mac on the server?**

I created another notebook and tried moving the notes one by one to this one but i get the following error.

```
The sections you're moving have not all been synced. Make sure you are online and fully synced before you move sections between notebooks.
```

Is there some way to get OneNote to ignore this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various options, this is what worked for me. It is not exactly what i was looking for but i was able to save my notes.
I used the OneNote 2016 (not the free one) to export all my sections to files.
***Note: You cannot do this for the whole notebook, fortunately you can export whole sections.(small mercies).***
These show up as 'Open Sections'. Once I had exported all my sections. I copied them one by one from the 'Open Sections' to another notebook. I synched this notebook and that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the instructions of this wiki:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-move-my-local-notebooks-to-OneDrive-or-SharePoint-7343c424-cdee-4bbf-9245-312549e81fc0

Comment: this does not work, it agains needs the synch to happen first. I am not able to do the synch because i accidentally deleted the file on OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer in this blog post: https://40north.wordpress.com/2020/01/10/salvaging-onenote-notes/comment-page-1/?unapproved=2063&moderation-hash=1ddd37becedb0462043fad528bd5d3b1#comment-2063

Essentially you need to:

1. Create a new notebook
2. Create new sections in that new notebook with the same labels as the old notebook (time consuming I know)
3. left click the top page in the old section, hold shift click and left click the bottom page
4. move those pages into the new section
5. repeat indefinitely

If someone can figure out how to write a script for this, that'd be great, but for now I'll just do it manually until it becomes tiresome.